# Fully qualified namespace within entities in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am currently working with EA, and have some issues with it not showing the full name space but rather only scope it up to its parent. There is a checkmark which include it, but the name space is then displayed outside the entity and not within, how do I make it appear within the entity and with the full namespace?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Maybe you can use a shape script with an add-in to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you sort of an answer: to my knowledge this is not possible natively in EA. The diagram property `Show FQN` is only working on embedded elements, not on the code engineering name space.

What you can do is to write an add-in to retrieve that name space by traversing the package structure up and building the FQN to the package which has set a code engineering name space root. This add-in can be called from within a shape script to print that name like `print("#addin:myAddIn,pFunc1#")` where `myAddIn` is the name of your add-in function and `pFunc1` is an optional parameter (list separated with comma) being passed.

I don't think it's worth the effort since that name can get quite long and unreadable in a class compartment. Alternatively think of the packages being shown nested and/or just a simple text/note to show the context name space.